# How to use Future as a state

Tags: flutter

I have a regular `FutureBuilder` that shows an image:

```
Future<Image> image;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  image = loadImage();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder<Image>(
      future: image,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // using snapshot.data
```

But what if I need to change the image later to a different, local image? Say:

```
Future<Image> filtered;
```

The logical way would be to use the existing `image` to load it from this other source, like:

```
setState(() {
  image = Future(() => filtered);
});
```

However, Flutter throws an error when a `Future` is returned in a `setSate` call *(setState() callback argument returned a Future)* suggesting to perform the async work and only setting the state with the result. Which is all right in the usual case, however, in this case the state itself is a `Future`, not the result of it.

Comment: `Future` is one shot only, you need a `Stream` and `StreamBuilder`

Comment: You can still make the widget statefull and use the setState in the .then of the future

Comment: @pskink: while that sounds a good idea, I never had problems with reusing FutureBuilders in different scenarios, simply loading again to get a new set of data.

Comment: @pskink: if you would like to copy my current answer as yours, I'd gladly remove mine so that you can take credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, the solution *pskink* suggested:

Turn the `Future` into a `Stream`:

```
StreamController<Image> image = StreamController<Image>();
```

Load it initially:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadImage().then((img) => image.add(img));
}
```

Use it almost exactly as before:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<Image>(
      stream: image.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // using snapshot.data
```

And use the same pattern whenever a new image should be displayed

```
image.add(filtered));
```

Comment: btw you could also use `AnimatedBuilder` or `StatefulBuilder`